# What is the idiomatic F# equivalent to declaring a variable for later use in C#

Tags: f#, immutability

In C# i can declare uninitialized variables that are then later assigned to in various methods of the class. For example, in an NUnit test i can declare a typed variable that is only initialized in a setup method and then repeatedly used in the various tests.

```
private MyTestClass sut;

public Setup()
{
    sut = new MyTestClass();
    etc.
}

public FirstTest()
{
    sut.DoSomeWork(1); 
}

public SecondTest()
{
    sut.DoSomeWork(2);
}
```

I would like to do the equivalent in F#. However according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086368/declaring-a-variable-without-assigning/11101281#11101281) and others, unassigned 'variables' is just not the done thing in F#.

In the case of my F# tests, the tests are not sitting in any type, just within a module so `[<DefaultValue>] val` won't work.
Using `mutable` just doesn't feel right as that seems to be the option of last resort for F# coders.

Since idomatic F# shouldn't require unassigned values, what is the "correct" way of getting around this problem?

Comment: What's wrong with `let sut = new MyTestClass()`?

Comment: Why do you need these variables? Is there a reason you can't declare them where you use them? In your C# example, the two tests can't be executed in parallel, you shot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Surely I shouldn't have to declare the variables each time where i use it. If each test requires an instance of that class that is identically initialized then that initialization should be in the setup. What would you do if you had a large number of tests and each test required a complex initialization of various helper classes. You wouldn't want to have to do that in each test. You'd stick it in a helper that would run before each test to initialize, i.e. the Setup method.Am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: @s952163, if i use `let sut = new MyTestClass()` then the value becomes immutable and is local within the context of my Setup function. However what i really want in the F# test is to declare it in such a way that i can access it in any subsequent test in the module. I can see that you could do that by declaring members within a `type`, but i'm under the impression that in F# i can just let the tests sit "free floating" so-to-speak in a module outside of a class? I'm very new to this functional stuff so please do correct if i'm thinking about things in the wrong way.

Comment: Forget the `Setup` function though, you don't need it.  You can just put `let sut = new MyTestClass()` in the module directly.

Comment: @FSharpOrBust if I had a large number of tests, each of which needed a complex initialization, I would put that initialization in a function, and call that function at the beginning of each test. The function would return a data structure with all components that the test needs to poke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use functions and values. There is no need to declare unassigned variables.

```
let makeTestClass() =
    MyTestClass()
    // etc.

let ``First test``() =
    let sut = makeTestClass()
    sut.DoSomeWork()

let ``Second test``() =
    let sut = makeTestClass()
    sut.DoSomeWork()
```

Comment: I don't see how this fits in with the context of having a Setup method? Doing this swaps declaring and initializing in each test (as suggested by Fyodor, above) for calling a method to return the test class. If this is the standard way of doing things in F# then i'd go with this, but i can't help but think i'm missing a trick here.

Comment: I'm saying don't use a Setup method. This is idiomatic F#. It's simple and it allows the tests to run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lazy`:

```
let sut = lazy (new MyTestClass())
```

`lazy` defers the execution of an expression until the result is needed.  Subsequent requests for the lazy value don't require it to be recomputed, it simply returns the stored result from last time.

Then you can do:

```
let ``First test``() =
    sut.Force().DoSomeWork(1)

let ``Second test``() =
    sut.Force().DoSomeWork(2)
```

This could be appropriate if initialisation is expensive and you don't wish to repeat it.